# Why does my testnet contuinously throw errors?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, rpc, testnet, payment-integration, payment

I have three private testnet nodes set up, and one wallet-rpc that connects to one of those three nodes (which are all connected to eachother as peers). I am constantly having to delete the walllet files, and the lmdb files, due to various errors. I have a PHP webapp that I am trying to get to accept XMR payments. To test it out, I have set up a private testnet with three nodes, one wallet for the e-commerce store (which is what the wallet-rpc uses), and one for the user (me). I am able to accept transactions, but the ability to refund is spotty at best. Sometimes I can refund at recieve the funds, sometimes I get an error, such as `[on_send_raw_tx]: tx verification failed: invalid input` or `Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem`, and sometimes the refund isn't recieved at all.

**All of these errors were fixed by restarting the testnet completely, ie, deleting lmdb files, and making new wallets.**

There was another error too, but I've forgetten the description, just remember it being extremely vague.

There are also errors with the gui wallet. Sometimes I get `not enough outputs for specified ring size` and other errors when trying to send transactions. Such as the `Dandelion++ stem` error.

For context:

I am using https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp

The script I use to start the testnet & GUI:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function cleanup {
    
    echo "Ctrl+C"
    pgrep monerod | xargs kill -1 2>/dev/null
    pgrep monero-wallet-r | xargs kill -1 2>/dev/null
    pgrep monero-wallet-gui | xargs kill -1 2>/dev/null
}

trap cleanup INT

#start node
echo "[+] Starting testnet node 1 p2p: localhost:8848 ~/node_04"
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "monerod --testnet --p2p-bind-port 8848 --rpc-bind-port 12231 --no-igd --hide-my-port  --log-level 2 --data-dir /home/user/node_04 --zmq-rpc-bind-port 55535 --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:28080 --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:29901 --fixed-difficulty 10 --disable-rpc-ban; sleep $1"

echo "[+] Starting testnet node 2 p2p: localhost:28080 ~/node_05"
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "monerod --testnet --no-igd --hide-my-port --data-dir /home/user/node_05 --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --p2p-bind-port 28080 --log-level 2 --zmq-rpc-bind-port 45535 --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:8848 --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:29901 --fixed-difficulty 10 --disable-rpc-ban; sleep $1"

echo "[+] Starting testnet node 3 p2p: localhost:29901 ~/node_06"
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "monerod --testnet --no-igd --hide-my-port --rpc-bind-port 29092 --data-dir /home/user/node_06 --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --p2p-bind-port 29901 --log-level 2 --zmq-rpc-bind-port 55531 --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:8848 --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:28080 --fixed-difficulty 10 --disable-rpc-ban; sleep $1"


echo "[+] Starting wallet RPC client"


gnome-terminal -- /home/user/testnet/wallet_rpc.sh

#start gui

echo "[+] Gui will start without text output"

/home/user/Desktop/monero-gui-v0.18.3.1/monero-wallet-gui >/dev/null
```

**I usually only get errors with the wallet RPC when the network has been running for a while (~ 3+ hrs)**